# Grails 3 Application Unable to load *.js file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, grails

I have my Grails 3 Application. I have placed my front-end application(which is built using Angular 2.1) in **src/main/webapp** folder.

While loading the application with URL http://localhost:8080/ I'm redirecting it to Index.html page.

But the Index.html page is not loading

URL:-http://localhost:8080/static/app-name/index.html

And I'm getting below errors in console.

> GET http://localhost:8080/inline.js 
>   index.html:14
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/main.78fb007fcde8966a4e95.bundle.js 
>   index.html:14
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/styles.d63e17da56bb3a1ca523.bundle.js 
>   index.html:14
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/main.78fb007fcde8966a4e95.bundle.js 404 ()

Comment: Are you using the default asset pipeline? If so, you should place your javascript files within: grails-app/assets/javascripts, then embed them using the g:asset tag.

Answer (score 0):

Change it so resources don't get served from the `/static` url:

`application.yml`:

```
grails:
    resources:
        pattern: /**
```

Comment: after making this change, I don't need static but I'm still facing same 404 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution.

> 1.) Copied the **contents of dist** *instead of dist folder itslef* into src/main/webapp
>
> 2.)Made the changes in **application.yml** as suggested by @James Kleeh.
>
> 3.)Re-Route controller uri to index.html.

And here it goes.

PS: I was actually facing path issue which got resolved following above steps